# Value can not be null, parameter name child or descendant

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

These lines of code cause my usercontrol to return the mentioned error in designer.
Am I missing something here?

```
    private void renewContext()
    {
        if (context != null)
        {
            context.Dispose();
            context = new SM_Context();
        }
        else
        {
            context = new SM_Context();
        }
    }
    private void tabPasswords_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source is TabControl)
        {
            TabControl tab = (TabControl)e.Source;
            switch (tab.SelectedIndex)
            {
                default:
                    break;
                case 0:
                    btnAP_Reset_Click(null, null);
                    btnEP_Reset_Click(null, null);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    btnEP_Reset_Click(null, null);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    btnAP_Reset_Click(null, null);
                    headEditPassword_Loaded(null, null);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is not the buttons and im sure, the problem is only with the context.
found out for some security reasons the tab changed wont allow me to renew the context inside it.
so how can i achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Any more explanation that you can provide?

Comment: Instead of `btnAP_Reset_Click(null, null)` extract handler body into separate method and call that method. Passing nulls is odd!

Comment: learningbycode im tryin to reset the context for each tab.

Comment: Use the debugger, find the exact line the error is occurring on.

Comment: lazyberezovsky i tried adding a handler but it's not what causes the problem. so i removed it.

Comment: the user control has no bug, and i cant add the usercontrol to designer to debug it.

Comment: @MehdiGhanavatian I'm not talking about adding handlers

Comment: You should only execute the body of the method if `e.Source` is not `null`. So put a check for that in it.

Answer (score 0):

As lazyberezovsky suggested as comment: Try to extract the logic you want to execute from the event handlers (`btnAP_Reset_Click` etc). It could look like this:

```
private void tabPasswords_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Source is TabControl)
    {
        TabControl tab = (TabControl)e.Source;
        switch (tab.SelectedIndex)
        {
            default:
                break;
            case 0:
                context = new SM_Context();
                ResetAp();
                ResetEp();
                break;
            case 1:
                context = new SM_Context();
                ResetEp();
                break;
            case 2:
                context = new SM_Context();
                ResetAp();
                WhatEverThisDoes();
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void ResetAp()
{
    // ...
}

private void ResetEp()
{
    // ...
}

private void WhatEverThisDoes()
{
    // ...
}

private void btnAP_Reset(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResetAp();
}

private void btnEP_Reset(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ResetEp();
}

private void headEditPassword_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WhatEverThisDoes();
}
```

Comment: the problem is not the buttons, its not right to send null refrence but as long as im controling the methods its ok.

Comment: @MehdiGhanavatian You added a line of code disposing the context field. Is this your productive code? This could fail if context is null.

Comment: sry i've changed that to a method controling the disposal.
the problem is now using is calling that method inside Tab Changed Event.

Answer (score 0):

You should lisen to the guys who wrote some comments on the question - but if you are determinded to use a button click - you could call `button.PerformClick()`

It would look something like this:

```
 btnAP_Reset.PerformClick();
```

this will not send the nullvalues as parameters to your implementation of the click event.

Comment: the problem is not the buttons, its not right to send null refrence but as long as im controling the methods its ok.